# determine webclient already downloaded all data/string

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm working with Windows Phone Apps and interacting with RESTful APIs (JSON). What I want to achieve is when I start loading all data it will showing a progress indicator and after all data is finished loading (which mean all data will be available in my `ListBox`) the progress indicator would disappear.

Here's the code I'm using but it doesn't seem to work:

```
try
{
   isBusy = true;
   isBusyMessage = "Loading...";
   WebClient client = new WebClient();
   Uri uri = new Uri(transportURL1 + latitude + "%2C" + longitude + transportURL2, UriKind.Absolute);
   client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
   {
     if (e.Error == null)
     {
       RootObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
       hereRestProperty = new ObservableCollection<Item>(result.results.items);
     }
     else
     {
       MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString());
     }
   };
   client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);

   isBusy = false;
   isBusyMessage = "Finished";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

`isBusy` is bound to my progress indicator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move isBusy = false; to DownloadStringCompleted handler, to change isBusy after download is completed:

```
isBusy = true;
isBusyMessage = "Loading...";
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    Uri uri = new Uri(transportURL1 + latitude + "%2C" + longitude + transportURL2, UriKind.Absolute);
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            RootObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
            hereRestProperty = new ObservableCollection<Item>(result.results.items);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString());
        }
        // Dispatcher.Invoke for lines below, if needed
        // Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => {
        isBusy = false;
        isBusyMessage = "Finished";
        // }));
    };
    client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do it with await. Unfortunately WP lacks method DownloadStringTaskAsync(), so to do that I'll make a method:

```
private Task<string> GetString(Uri uri)
{
   TaskCompletionSource<string> taskComplete = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
   WebClient client = new WebClient();
   client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
   {
     if (e.Error == null) taskComplete.SetResult(e.Result);
     else taskComplete.SetException(e.Error);
   };
   client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
   return taskComplete.Task;
}

private async Task myTask()            
{
  isBusy = true;
  isBusyMessage = "Loading...";
  Uri uri = new Uri(transportURL1 + latitude + "%2C" + longitude + transportURL2, UriKind.Absolute);
  string resultDownload = await GetString(uri);
  try
  {
    RootObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(resultDownload);
    hereRestProperty = new ObservableCollection<Item>(results.items);
  }
  catch (Exception err)                 
  {
    MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
  }
  isBusy = false;
  isBusyMessage = "Finished";
}
```

It's just another way to do that - for me it's just simpler to do that. In this case you have an async task, which you can await or not.

Comment: @LaurensiusTony it's just another way to do what you want, it also depends on the rest of the code. But your solution will also work fine.